# How to do it in a single press instead of pressing 3 times to button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior, Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class Gui(App):
    def build(self):
        self.iscapturepressed = False
        self.countdown = 3
        self.button = ImageButton(source = 'Button.png', size_hint = (None, None), width = 250, height = 250, pos = (300, 300), on_press = self.capture)

        self.r3 = Image(source = 'r3.png', size_hint = (None, None), width = 435, height = 783, pos = (0, 0))
        self.r2 = Image(source = 'r2.png', size_hint = (None, None), width = 435, height = 783, pos = (0, 0))
        self.r1 = Image(source = 'r1.png', size_hint = (None, None), width = 435, height = 783, pos = (0, 0))

        self.layout = FloatLayout()
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 30)

        return self.layout

    def capture(self, *args):
        while self.countdown:
            if self.countdown == 3:
                self.layout.add_widget(self.r3)
                print("3")
                self.countdown -= 1
                return self.capture
            elif self.countdown == 2:
                self.layout.remove_widget(self.r3)
                self.layout.add_widget(self.r2)
                print("2")
                self.countdown -= 1
                return self.capture
            elif self.countdown == 1:
                self.layout.remove_widget(self.r2)
                self.layout.add_widget(self.r1)
                print("1")
                self.countdown -= 1
                return self.capture
            self.layout.remove_widget(self.r1)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 30)
        return self.layout

    def update(self, *args):
        pass

Gui().run()
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I'm a new software developer and at this gui I want to make countdown timer (3 to 1) with using .png files of numbers.My button at gui countsdown when I press three times (3 to 1). 
However, I want this countdown when pressed once to the button.
I need Help.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def capture(self, *args):
    if self.countdown == 3:
        self.layout.add_widget(self.r3)
        print("3")
    elif self.countdown == 2:
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.r3)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.r2)
        print("2")
    elif self.countdown == 1:
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.r2)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.r1)
        print("1")
    elif self.countdown == 0:
        # done
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.r1)
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 30)  # already started in build() method
        self.countdown = 3
        return

    self.countdown -= 1
    Clock.schedule_once(self.capture, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using elif statements, meaning the program will execute once per button press. Changing the elif statements to if statements might work.

```
def capture(self, *args):
        while self.countdown:
            if self.countdown == 3:
                self.layout.add_widget(self.r3)
                print("3")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 30)
                self.countdown -= 1
                return self.capture
            if self.countdown == 2:
                self.layout.remove_widget(self.r3)
                self.layout.add_widget(self.r2)
                print("2")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 30)
                self.countdown -= 1
                return self.capture
            if self.countdown == 1:
                self.layout.remove_widget(self.r2)
                self.layout.add_widget(self.r1)
                print("1")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 30)
                self.countdown -= 1
                return self.capture
            self.layout.remove_widget(self.r1)

        return self.layout

    def update(self, *args):
        pass

Gui().run()
```

Give that shot and tell me how it runs. I just kinda threw it together and without seeing everything I don't know the exact solution

Comment: I changed elif statements to if statement but same problem exist!! How can I share my gui to you